# Evaluate Azure ARM template before deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I want to evaluate ARM template file which contains actual values passed by the user before it passed to deployment engine.

Is there any way to do that?

I have started creating evaluation code through PEGJS library of nodejs by using which I can evaluate only particular condition or expression present in AZURE ARM functions but can't evaluate actual template which is passed to deployment engine to create any service.

Also, I have checked sdk azure-rest-client but can't find any way please help me to find the solution for the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way of doing that, you can use validate deployment [api call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/validate) (its also implemented in different sdk's\cli's) but it doesnt actually guarantee that the template will work, it does some basic sanity checks.

You best bet is to write a script that would deploy the template and a set of tests that would validate the outcode.

Comment: Thanks for the information 4c74356b41. Is there any way to get actual template values before the deployment is done.

For example: if I am created one ARM template for service Azure relay and deployed the same using CLI. That time user passing some values to that deployment like relay_name etc so I need to get the template with those values entered by user.

Comment: check the validate api call response values, but I dont think they are being expanded. overall I dont understand the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I am trying to get the ARM template which having parameter values as the user is given while deploying it.
The example of native ARM template azure relay namespace service is (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-azure-relay-create-namespace/azuredeploy.json), in this, there is a resources section and I want to evaluate the value for [parameters('name')] which is passed by the user while deploying the same usually we are passing those values through parameters.json.

Comment: i dont understand, define evaluate? why do you need to evaluate it and what it means exactly?

Comment: Evaluate in my case is if user deployed above service through CLI by passing the parameters.json, the internal resources section is got replaced with the parameters specified in (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-azure-relay-create-namespace/azuredeploy.parameters.json) the file. In this case, I need the following evaluation "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-07-01",
      "name": "GEN-UNIQUE","type": "Microsoft.Relay/Namespaces",
      "location": "east-us",
      "kind": "Relay",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
} I want this values.

Comment: arm template doesnt care and doesnt know how it was invoked. there is no way of knowing that